# Windows desktop file/folder log, monitor

Tags: windows, file-management, monitoring, logs, desktop-environment

OS : windows 10

If I right-click background of desktop, there is a shell menu that shows the most recent event that has happened, and you can undo the event. But it is for just 1 most recent event and doesn't tell more.

I am finding a software that logs(in real time) almost everthing that happens in desktop.

For example the software logs events like
files/folders/shortcuts that were created,downloaded,renamed,deleted,moved from or to.

There are some software that can do similar work for windows explorer, but I couldn't find a software that is specialized for windows desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [process monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/sysinternals-suite/9p7knl5rwt25) from sysinternals.com / microsoft

This software will show you in realtime what all processes are doing and has the option for logging.